# What happens to characters and/or items inside a creature that is banished by the Banishment spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

What happens to the other characters or items inside the one banished by a *banishment* spell?

- Are they banished with it?
- Do they stay behind and fall to the floor?
- Is there a difference between what happens characters and items?

Comment: Are you asking about cases such as when one creature swallows another? If so this question exists: "[What happens to swallowed creatures when Banishment is cast on the creature that swallowed them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114166)"

Comment: Chris, can you review the linked question and see whether it matches yours?